# Kubernetes deploy a single NodePort for two deployments in different namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment

I have to deploy on my kubernetes cluster two deployments that use the same service for communicate but the two deployments are located into two differents namespaces:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1
  namespace: namespace1
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app1
          image: eu.gcr.io/direct-variety-20998876/test1:dev
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "100m"
              memory: "128Mi"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
              ...
```

and an identical second but in another amespace:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app2
  namespace: namespace2
  labels:
    app: app2
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app2
          image: eu.gcr.io/direct-variety-20998876/test1:prod
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "100m"
              memory: "128Mi"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
              ...
```

so i have to create a common service for bot deployment that run over the two namespaces:
I try:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apps-service
  namespace: ???
spec:
  selector:
    app: ???
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  type: NodePort
```

Until now i create one service for any app in specific namespace but there is a method for create a single service for manage both deployment (and then associate an unique ingress)?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Services are namespaced.
What do you mean by `associate an unique ingress` ?

Comment: I would create an unique ingress between the two apps in different namespaces for example  https://32.12.33.40/app1 for appi and /app2 for app2 without create two different ingress one for any app

Comment: Which [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) do you want to use ?

Comment: Nginx cold be good

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to provide some general explanations.
As we can see in the [Ingress documentation](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#prerequisites):

> You must have an Ingress controller to satisfy an Ingress. Only creating an Ingress resource has no effect.

**[Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/)** can be deployed in any namespace and is often deployed in a namespace separate from the application namespace.

**[Ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource)** (Ingress rules) should be deployed in the same namespace as the services they point to.

It is possible to have one ingress controller for multiple ingress resources.

Deploying an `Ingress` resource in the same namespace as the `Services` it points to is the most common approach (I recommend this approach).
However, there is way to have `Ingress` in one namespace and `Services` in another namespaces using [externalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) Services.

---

I will create an example to illustrate how it may work.

Suppose, I have two `Deployments` (`app1`, `app2`) deployed in two different `Namespaces` (`namespace1`, `namespace2`):

```
$ cat app1.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app1
  name: app1
  namespace: namespace1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
    
$ cat app2.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app2
  name: app2
  namespace: namespace2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app2
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
```

And I exposed these `Deployments` with `ClusterIP` `Services`:

```
$ cat svc-app1.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app1
  name: app1
  namespace: namespace1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: app1
    
$ cat svc-app2.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app2
  name: app2
  namespace: namespace2
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: app2
```

We want to have a single `Ingress` resource in a separate `Namespace` (`default`).
First, we need to deploy Services of type ExternalName that map a Service to a DNS name.

```
$ cat external-app1.yml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: external-app1
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: app1.namespace1.svc
  
$ cat external-app2.yml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: external-app2
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: app2.namespace2.svc
```

Then we can deploy Ingress resource:

```
$ cat ingress.yml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /app1
            backend:
              serviceName: external-app1
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /app2
            backend:
              serviceName: external-app2
              servicePort: 80
              
$ kubectl apply -f ingress.yml
ingress.networking.k8s.io/app-ingress created
```

Finally, we can check if it works as expected:

```
$ curl 34.118.X.207/app1
app1
$ curl 34.118.X.207/app2
app2
```

**NOTE:** This is a workaround and may work differently with different ingress controllers. It is ususally better to have two or more Ingress resources in different namespaces.